# Programmatically Query Private Function Address (PE Executable)

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I have recently written a simple test program to call a few private functions in a DLL that ships with Windows. Since private functions are not exported, their address cannot be found with GetProcAddress(), and I am looking for a way to achieve the same without it.

With IDA Pro, I took note of the offset of an exported function, DllRegisterServer in this case. Since this function is exported, I can query its address with GetProcAddress. By knowing its offset from the beginning of the .text section of the PE executable, I can then dynamically query the address of the .text section after loading the DLL with LoadLibrary.

Again, still using IDA Pro, I took note of the offsets of each of the private functions of interest. Once I have the address of the .text section, I only need to add the offset for the known private functions and I now have the correct address to call those functions. There is only one problem, however: since the offset has been hardcoded, this will only work with this exact version of the DLL.

I know there are many tools that can read PE and give addresses of private functions. I assume that the debug symbols are used to query the names of those private functions. What I'm looking for is a simple library that can read PE and debug symbols and allow me to query by name the address of a private function.

Does anybody know of such a library that can help find the addresses of private function by names, making use if debug symbols when available?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just an update: I have been able to use the examples from MSDN to find private symbols for my current program. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to automatically load a .pdb corresponding to a Microsoft DLL using the symbol servers. I found a really helpful set of examples of how to use the dbghelp API here: http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/dbghelpexamples.html. However, nothing which really shows how to get the .pdb for a specific .dll, in the same way symchk.exe does it.